# jQuery object removes HTML markup

Tags: jquery

So, I am converting a HTML code to a jQuery object, where I want to edit it slightly.
In this case I simply want to remove the images from the content. For some reason it removes more than that.

Checking the below HTML markups you will also see that the `tr`'s are also removed along with the content of the second tr.

jQuery

```
var getHTML = '';

$('.option-'+ optionNumber).each(function(){ //optionNumber in this very example is 0 and thus will select the below trs with class option-0
    getHTML += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
    });

var newHTML = $(getHTML);
newHTML.find('img').remove();
```

Original HTML markup:

```
<tr class="option-0">
   <td>
      1
   </td>
   <td>
      Simple
   </td>
   <td>
      <img alt="" src="gfx/man_icon.gif">
   </td>
   <td id="thisOptionPrice0" rowspan="2">
      $450.00
   </td>
   <td id="thisSelectionOption0" rowspan="2" style="width: 100px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
              <div class="ui-radio">
                  <label class="chooseLabel ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off" for="packageOption-0">Elegir</label>
                  <input data-cacheval="false" name="selectReservation" data-optionnumber="0" class="selectReservationOption" onclick="selectPackageOption(0); return false;" id="packageOption-0" value="1|1@2|1" type="radio">
              </div>
          </fieldset>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="option-0">
   <td>
      1
   </td>
   <td>
      Doble
   </td>
   <td>
      <img alt="" src="gfx/man_icon.gif">
   </td>
</tr>
```

RESULT:

```
<td>
  1
</td>
<td>
 Doble
</td>
<td></td>
<td id="thisOptionPrice0" rowspan="1">
   $300.00
</td>
<td id="thisSelectionOption0" rowspan="1">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <div class="ui-radio">
                <label class="chooseLabel ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off" for="packageOption-0">Elegir</label>
                <input data-cacheval="false" name="selectReservation" data-optionnumber="0" class="selectReservationOption" onclick="selectPackageOption(0); return false;" id="packageOption-0" value="2|1" type="radio">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</td>
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Doing it like this it seems to get the first tr right.. but forgets about the second one:
    var getHTML = '';

```
$('.option-'+ optionNumber).each(function(){ //optionNumber in this very example is 0 and thus will select the below trs with class option-0
    getHTML += '<table>'+ $(this)[0].outerHTML +'</table>;
    });
```

What's going on here?

**Solved - This did the trick**

```
var getHTML = '';
var finalHTML = '';
$('.option-'+ optionNumber).each(function(){
    getHTML = '<tbody>'+ $(this)[0].outerHTML +'</tbody>';
    var newHTML = $(getHTML);

    newHTML.find('img').remove();
    finalHTML += newHTML.html();
    });
```

Thank you everyone for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

To anwser the questuion 'what's going on'...

When you create jquery object like this: `var newHTML = $('<tr>one</tr><tr>two</tr>')`, it cannot create correct html element.

You should either pass array to jquery object, or wrap your `<tr>`s in a table to present it as a correct table object.

```
var newHTML = $("<table>"+getHTML+"</table>");
newHTML.find('img').remove();
```

Comment: This was the closest answer to solve my problem. Gave me some ideas, so one up.

Comment: also its better to make `img`s and `inputs` tags closed `<img src="..." />`, otherwise this may cause troubles sometimes

Comment: Uhuh, they are! Not sure why they're shown as not closed in my console log.

Answer (score 0):

what does the following do ?

```
$(".option0 img").remove()
```

(try it)

Comment: Well, that will also remove the image from the original piece of HTML. I don't want that. I want to remove the image from the HTML that my object is holding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var _temp = $("table").clone();

$(_temp).find("tr img").remove()

$("body").append(_temp)
```

[Check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0czjxk12/1/)

Comment: Nope, it does remove the images from the original piece of HTML. I don't want that. I want to go inside of my object containing that piece and remove them and create a new piece of HTML :)

Comment: this will remove all images from temp variable,

Comment: Nope, I had no success with it.
Figured it out. I will post the solution to my thread.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all of the `<img>`'s from your webpage, simply do `$("img").remove()`.

Working code snippet:

```js
$("img").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="option-0">
  <td>
    1
  </td>
  <td>
    Simple
  </td>
  <td>
    <img alt="" src="gfx/man_icon.gif" >
  </td>
  <td id="thisOptionPrice0" rowspan="2">
    $450.00
  </td>
  <td id="thisSelectionOption0" rowspan="2" style="width: 100px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <div class="ui-radio">
          <label class="chooseLabel ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off" for="packageOption-0">Elegir</label>
          <input data-cacheval="false" name="selectReservation" data-optionnumber="0" class="selectReservationOption" onclick="selectPackageOption(0); return false;" id="packageOption-0" value="1|1@2|1" type="radio">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="option-0">
  <td>
    1
  </td>
  <td>
    Doble
  </td>
  <td>
    <img alt="" src="gfx/man_icon.gif">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not at all what I want to do ;) I want to remove the images that are only inside of the markup that my object newHTML holds :)